# Run aws codebuild build only if the change occur on a specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a small microservice app and i want to use codebuild with codepipeline to implemant a ci/cd pipeline

The structure of my project looks like this:

project-folder

> service-1
>
> > - buildspec.yaml
> > - Dockerfile

> service-2
>
> > - buildspec.yaml
> > - Dockerfile

What i want to do is to run a build only if a change occurred on a specific service.
How can i use regex with FILE_PATH filter to run build only if a change occurred on a specific service ?

I tried using filters with codebuild webhooks by setting FILE_PATH=^service-1/.* but it doesn't work as expected because it runs all builds.

Comment: It's `FILE_PATH` not `PATH_FILE`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/webhooks.html

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo when i tried to write the problem.
Thank you for your response.

Comment: You mentioned you are using CodePipeline in addition to CodeBuild. If you are using CodePipeline to manage your CodeBuild tasks, then you typically would not also be using a webhook to trigger a CodeBuild task. Can you explain in more detail how you are triggering a build?

Comment: I trigger the pipeline when a PULL REQUEST MERGED event occur in the context of the main branch.

Comment: That explains when you trigger it, but not how. Are you using GitHub, AWS CodeCommit, GitLab? How specifically are you propagating that `PULL REQUEST MERGED` event into CodePipeline? Since you are using CodePipeline, the configuration you made for the CodeBuild webhook isn't going to be used at all. So you need to explain exactly how you are triggering CodePipeline so we can help.

Comment: I'm using github as source,my pipeline is confugured to run whene a change is occured on the main branch.
I have one single action on source phase but multiple build actions (for each service) so that they can run on parallel.
I have to phases one for source phase and the second one is for builds.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you want with your setup of a single pipeline for all microservices. You would need to do something like create separate pipelines per microservice, and have a GitHub action configured for each one, that triggers the corresponding CodePipeline.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so helpful i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.